# Unable to attach with upstream node using node rejoin

Tags: postgresql, database-administration, repmgr

Trying to join with my upstream node1 but unable to do it. Just showing a warning like
**WARNING: node "node2" not found in "pg_stat_replication"** . Where is the issue? and how can I join with node1 it?

This is the replication slot status:
[image]

Below is the node status:
[image]

Below is the node rejoin error:
[image]

Try using standby follow but showing below error
[image]

Answer (score 1):

First a tip : paste text, not screenshots.
There can be a few causes.
In my case, one cause was the lack of a restore of the postgresql.conf after a repmgr/barman restore. Make sure that file is correct both on master and slave.

Another cause can be that your repmgr command looks in different spots. As far as I understand it, that data is also in a database and that also syncs between nodes.
The error indicates that in the data known by repmgr, the second node is not registered. You can try to reregister it, but I think it has something to do with the above mentioned settings - lack of rights or syncing of the database.

To register run on the standby node:

```
repmgr standby register -F
```

If you cannot get it to work, the easiest way to get back to running properly is to clone, by running this on the standby node :

```
repmgr standby clone --force -h node1 -U repmgr -d repmgr
```

where node1 is your primary.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue with postgresql-13 and repmgr-13, so this bug is definitely not fixed.

All I could do is recreate the standby from scratch, which is really a pain in the ...

Comment: hi, did you do that with cloning? I get another issue doing that. Details are appreciated, thank you.